# Is the SNR of two images in MATLAB correct?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Below is the algorithm for calculating the SNR of two images in MATLAB:

```
ref = imread('No_Noise.png');

A = imread('Yes_Noise.png');
A = imresize(A, [512 512]);

test = snr(A, ref)
```

I just want to ask, what does come first and last in the last line? `A` as the noisy image and `REF` as the not noisy image (in this particular case I get a negative result)? Or `REF` as not the noisy image and `A` as the noisy image (in this particular case I get a positive result)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Citing the [documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/snr.html):

> `r = snr(x,y)` returns the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR) in decibels of a signal, `x`, by computing the ratio of its summed squared magnitude to that of the noise, `y`. `y` must have the same dimensions as `x`. Use this form when the input signal is not necessarily sinusoidal and you have an estimate of the noise.

So, in your case, get the pure noise by subtracting the two:

```
test = snr(A,A-ref)
```